# Integral map $Tf(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(s) d s$ is not a contraction on $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Q. Let $T: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ be a mapping defined by
$$
T f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(s) d s
$$
Show that: $T$ is NOT a contraction but $T^{2}$ is a contraction.

It seems to me that
$\begin{aligned}\left|\int_{0}^{x}(f(s)-g(s)) d s\right| & \leq \operatorname{sup}_{[0,1]}|f(s)-g(s)| \int_{0}^{x} d s \\ & \leq \sup _{[0,1]} |f(s)-g(s) |\end{aligned}$
What point I have missed here?

Comment: If it were a contraction, shouldn't the coefficient be less than $1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611160/proving-a-function-is-not-a-contraction?rq=1 will help

Comment: For a contraction mapping, the final line in the inequality would need to be $\le k \sup_{s \in [0,1]} |f(s) - g(s)|$, where $k$ is a constant that is strictly less than one. e.g., $k=0.99$ would suffice.